# Scala Play "Can't resolve symbol db"

Tags: postgresql, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've been trying to connect to a local postgres from Scala Play but for some reason can't seem to be able to import `Database` and `NamedDatabase`.

When trying to import with `import play.api.db._` or `import play.api.db.{ Database, NamedDatabase }`, I receive a `Can't resolve symbol db` error. This literally makes 0 sense. I've tried re-importing the project and rebuilding in IntelliJ but it still won't work. Did something change with the `db` import that's undocumented? These import statements come directly from the Scala Play tutorial page:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase

I've also included the postgres dependency in `build.sbt` but I think that's irrelevant:

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
```

Here's an image showing what's going on:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I simply forgot to add a dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += jdbc
```

This fixed everything.